# Python build error on HPUX

Tags: python, gcc, python-2.7, python-3.x, hp-ux

I am trying to build both Python 2.7.4 and Python 3.3.1 on HPUX 11.31 Itanium with gcc 4.7.0. For both projects, I am getting the same build error:

```
make
...

running build scripts

...

/bin/sh[5]: 26906 Abort (coredump)
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 134
```

I can't find anything recent or relevant about this error. I can build Python 2.7.3 using the same process, and it builds fine. We have a working Python 3.1.2 that I built a while ago, also using the same process.

My configure line is simple:

```
./configure --prefix="some path" --with-threads
```

I have tried with and without threads. I am also building a 64 bit version, using "-mlp64"

Comment: Are you comfortably with analyzing a coredump using gdb? I guess it will be hard to get an answer here, the rarity of your platform alone makes the answer too specific.

Comment: I agree. HPUX really sucks. We were hoping to be on Linux at this point.

Comment: Did you check the `configure` log?  And what exactly causes the crash?  Was it gcc?

Comment: That's the problem I can't determine what is causing the crash. I have done "make --debug=v" and it doesn't provide any more information.